# GCP: How can I take backup of an instance that is mount to the file store or basically I want to take a backup of file store in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a file store in `google cloud platform` and mount it to one of the vm instance now I want to take the backup of the instance, now I know for backup we can use snapshot but it is not working.

```
for example:- I created one file as file1 in my mount-point-directory take the snapshot of the machine and delete that file1, then used the snapshot disk but I didn't get my file back.
```

So is there any way to take the backup of file store instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely where are stored your files? In a disk? on Google Cloud Storage? You mention Google cloud platform that is not a specific product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a solution from partner to Backup your file store since the snapshots are only for Persistent disks and nothing else and in your case File store is a different resource. Flie store is mounted to the VM but is not a part of the VM instance itself, it is like a external device like USB for example.

You can check this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/backup) for backup File store options